# Lost session data after MS AD Oauth2 redirect

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0

I am losing original session data after MS AD Oauth2 redirect back today. It is now a totally new session after redirect to and back from https://login.microsoftonline.com/**************/oauth2/v2.0/authorize". But, it worked a few days ago and failed now after some automatic windows10 updates (and rekeying some tfs password from credential manager.) However, If I use my GitHub authorization server, the same code works and keeps my session data: Session["state"]. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am doing manual redirection using something like below:

```
    private void SignUpOAuth()
    {
        var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var clientId = "*************";
        var scope = "openid";
        var serviceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("OAuthServiceUrl");
        var redirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("OAuthRedirectUrl");

        var paramtersPart = string.Format("response_type={0}&client_id={1}&scope={2}&redirect_uri={3}&aud{4}&state={5}&nonce={6}&response_mode=form_post",
            "id_token+code",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientId),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(scope),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectUrl),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(serviceUrl),
            state,
            nonce);

        _context.Session.Add("state", state);
        _context.Session.Add("nonce", nonce);

        _context.Response.Redirect($"{ serviceUrl}?{paramtersPart}", false);
    }
```

Comment: correction: However, If I use GitHub authorization server, the same code works and keeps my session data: Session["state"].

Comment: I noticed MS AD authorization server hit Session_Start of Global.asax.cs while GitHub  authorization server does not when they send back "code".

Comment: Could be related to this: https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html?